# swift check date is today or tomorrow

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an integer array which is a collection of today's and tomorrow's dates, I want to separate the integer array based on the type of day

```
let dateCollection = [
    1633722900,
    1633730500,
    1633754910,
    1633758913,
    1633820400,
    1633824000,
    1633827600,
    1633831200,
    1633834800,
    1633838400,
    1633842000
   ]
```

**expected result**

```
let today: [Int] = [
    1633722900,
    1633730500,
    1633754910,
    1633758913
]

let tomorrow: [Int] = [  
    1633820400,
    1633824000,
    1633827600,
    1633831200,
    1633834800,
    1633838400,
    1633842000
]
```

what should i do to separate them, i have made an extension to convert the integer to date or vice versa, and display it as a time, i already create the date to time extension too

```
func getTimetringFromINT() -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(self))
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "id")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

[selector i made, after convert the date to Time string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cCKV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Calendar.current.ordinality` to compare the day of the year for the various dates. Here's an example that generates dates from today and tomorrow and then filters them back into separate arrays:

```
let today = Date()
let todayInts = Array(0..<10).map { today.timeIntervalSince1970 + TimeInterval($0) }
print("Today:", todayInts,"\n")

let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)!
let tomorrowInts = Array(0..<10).map { tomorrow.timeIntervalSince1970 + TimeInterval($0) }
print("Tomorrow:", tomorrowInts,"\n")

let allInts = todayInts + tomorrowInts

let todayDayOfYear = Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: today)!

let filteredTodayInts = allInts.filter { Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: $0)) == todayDayOfYear }
print("Filtered today:", filteredTodayInts,"\n")

let tomorrowDayOfYear = todayDayOfYear + 1

let filteredTomorrowInts = allInts.filter { Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: $0)) == tomorrowDayOfYear }
print("Filtered tomorrow:", filteredTomorrowInts,"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to do this would be to calculate the int value of midnight between today and tomorrow and then split the array based on that value

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var today = [Int]()
var tomorrow = [Int]()
if let midnight = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: calendar.startOfDay(for: .now))?.timeIntervalSince1970 {
    let limit = Int(midnight)
    dateCollection.forEach { $0 < limit ? today.append($0) : tomorrow.append($0) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to get the start date of the next day (regardless of daylight saving time changes) with the `Calendar` API and then [partition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition) the array

```
let startOfTomorrow = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), 
                                       matching: DateComponents(hour: 0), 
                                       matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
                                      .timeIntervalSince1970
let splitIndex = dateCollection.partition{ $0 < Int(startOfTomorrow) }
let tomorrowDates = dateCollection[..<splitIndex]
let todayDates = dateCollection[splitIndex...]
```

To be able to run this declare `dateCollection` as `var`

Answer (score 0):

By Getting StartOfDay of any Time, we can classify all Date that shares the same StartOfDay.

```swift
extension Date {
    var morning: Date { Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self) }
    var nextMorning: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)!.morning }
}
extension Int {
    var since1970: Date { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(self)) }
}
```

In this case:

```swift
let todayMorning    = Date().morning     // Date().advanced(by: 3600*24 * -19).morning
let tomorrowMorning = Date().nextMorning // Date().advanced(by: 3600*24 * -19).nextMorning

let dateCollection  = [ ... ]

let today    = dateCollection.filter{ $0.since1970.morning == todayMorning }
let tomorrow = dateCollection.filter{ $0.since1970.morning == tomorrowMorning }
```

Comment: *`86400` math* is strongly discouraged, because days where daylight saving time changes can have `82800` or `90000`